# v-dialog not formatting as expected

Tags: vue.js, modal-dialog, vuetify.js

### Currently dialog is showing as below.

[image: Current dialog]

### Expected to show as below

[image: How to show]

### html markup

```
  <v-dialog v-model="dialog" width="500">
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
      <v-btn v-on="on">Click</v-btn>
    </template>
    <v-card>
      <v-card-title primary-title>Details</v-card-title>
      <v-card-text>Hello</v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
```

The script has `dialog` in the data property.
I am trying to achieve the same look and feel as shown in the documentation.
Using `"vuetify": "^2.0.1",` `"vuetify-loader": "^1.3.0"`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add "grey lighten-2" to the v-card-title to achieve the grey background effect. Add the following to your code if you want the divider and action button as well:

```
          <v-divider></v-divider>

          <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn
              color="primary"
              text
              @click="dialog = false"
            >
              I accept
            </v-btn>
          </v-card-actions>
```

The code for the documentation is [here](https://codepen.io/pen/?editors=1010).

Comment: The issue is not with Card formatting. It's with rest of the page. It's currently showing Dark Grey, instead of transparent grey

Comment: Are you able to reproduce your issue in codepen? You might have styles that are over-writing the modal background.